# Встраивание другого приложения в свое

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть приложение, написанное на каком-то языке.
Данное приложение не имеет API, но имеет некоторый интерфейс.

Как можно воспользоваться функциями данного приложения в своем незаметно для пользователя?

На ум приходит только прятанье куда-нибудь этого приложение и жудкое взаимодействие с окном через WinAPI, например биндинг кнопок на свое приложение.

Какие-нибудь еще варианты?

С .NET приложениями все более менее ясно, больше интересует работа с нативным приложением.

Comment: Если это нативщина и API нет, отстается только как вы описали, но может и еще хуже. Если приложение использует гуи фрэймворк с одним главныс окном, а все остальное рисует фрэймворк, там и это не сработает.

Comment: @Vasek, соответственно если случай, который вы описали имеет место быть, то взаимодействовать никак незя будет?

Comment: ну насколько мне известно(слышал но даже в глаза не видел как это работает) есть один более менее универсальный метод используемый тестовыми программами. Они как правило записывают макрос последовательностей кликов и потом его воспроизводят. В теории можно реализовать чтото похожие.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer**

*Это лишь один из способов решения задачи, предполагающий некоторые допущения, не оговариваемые в вопросе. Это решение возможно не подойдет в большинстве случаев, в том числе и задавшему вопрос.*

Если это .NET приложение (судя по тегам), его возможно декомпилировать с помощью таких утилит как [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy#ilspy-------). Достаточно отыскать обработчики событий нажатия интересующих кнопок.

Файл .exe (если это .NET приложение) возможно подключить к .NET проекту как обычную сборку, вызывать конструкторы классов и их методы используя [Reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection).

Это решение предполагает что:

1. Используемые методы либо статические, либо экземпляры соотвествующих классов не требуют сложной инициализации.
2. Используемые методы не требуют реакции пользователя, либо используют диалоговые окна идеально вписывающиеся в UI вашей программы.
3. Используемые методы либо возвращают результат, либо другим желанным образом воздействуют на окружение.
4. Это обычное не обфусцированное .NET приложение.

Comment: Забудьте про рефлектор, ILSpy гораздо лучше работает да еще и бесплатный к тому же.

Comment: C# все понятно. Более менее. Больше интересует работа с нативным приложением.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо